# How to get a specific jQuery item from a list of items?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, indexing, sizzle

I have this:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Then I select it all with jQuery: `$('ul').find('li');` or `$('ul li');`

How can I, from those two jQuery selectors get the, for instance only second li, or third, and to leave first and fourt alone?

I thought it might work with:

```
$('myselector').get(indexNumber); // however, it won't work.
```

Any ideas for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work?  That is correct.  In fact that is almost the exact example on jquery's page? http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: somehow it doesn't work... do not know why!

Comment: my example: $('li').get(0).show(); ? returns that it's not a function at all.

Comment: it works with eq and nth-child though. :) thanks!

Comment: try to alert($('ul li').get(0)) what it will give you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `get` method returns the DOM element, so then you would have to wrap it inside a new jQuery object.

You can use the `eq` method:

```
var j = $('ul li').eq(1); // gets the second list item
```

Comment: thanks, works perfectly with eq function, or in jQuery selector argument ;) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). For for example, for second element use:

```
 $("ul li:eq(1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 1):

$('li').get(0) will return plain DOM element. you cannot call jQuery methods on same.

Comment: thank you for the tip man, I didn't know it before man. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nth-child`

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)") //this will select second child because it is 1 based index
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xyyWh/