# Select the Nth item from a jQuery array or object list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get nth jQuery element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442925/how-to-get-nth-jquery-element)
>   [Get an element by index in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887534/get-an-element-by-index-in-jquery)

What is the jQuery equivalent of the square brackets **[ ]** indexing notation for selecting the ***Nth*** item from an array?

Say you have 10 paragraphs and want to get the contents of the 7th one. Using square bracket notation works, but not if you want to keep using jQuery:

```
$("p")[6];        //returns DOM object: [object HTMLParagraphElement]
$("p")[6].html(); //returns error: (Chrome:) Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLParagraphElement> has no method 'html' (Firefox:) TypeError: $("p")[6].html is not a function (IE8+:) TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method (IE7:) [object Error]
```

([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmdgx/))

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked many times before. Why add another  question and answer?

Comment: HUH?  Why ask a question then post an Answer right away?

Comment: @Wirey: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/
@ am no i am: I just spent a good amount of time trying to figure this out and many searches to stack overflow didn't bring up a question that answered this directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get an element by index in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887534/get-an-element-by-index-in-jquery) or this... [How to get a specific jQuery item from a list of items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514448/how-to-get-a-specific-jquery-item-from-a-list-of-items)

Comment: @wirey, brentonstrine: It's fine to ask and answer your own question, but not if it's a dupe.

Comment: That's what I meant.  This question has been asked/answered so many times already

Comment: but this isn't anything new, this question has been asked and answered many many times before. It's not like you are providing the community some new, novel information, you're just wasting time and space

Comment: I see the link there, somehow it didn't come up in my searches--probably because I didn't know enough about what I was asking to use the right keywords. I tried to craft this question so that the keywords would bring it up, but I see that it is indeed a duplicate. Sorry!

Comment: You can delete it you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square bracket [n] index notation works but you get the native Javascript DOM object, not something that jQuery can work with. Use jQuery's [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)  or the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get a jQuery object.

```
$("p").eq(6).html();
$("p:eq(6)").html();
```

([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmdgx/1/))