# How to make second li active using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery tab. I have to select the second tab by default. But I have a problem with assigning the `active` class to the second `li`. Below is the code to add the `active` class to first `li`. How can I edit the code below to make second `li` active instead:

```
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514448/how-to-get-a-specific-jquery-item-from-a-list-of-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$("ul.tabs li:eq(1)").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$("ul.tabs li:eq(1)").addClass("active");
```

Read [:eq-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

**or**

```
$("ul.tabs li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass("active");
```

Read [nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

**Using** `jquery ui` [option-active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) you can use

```
$( "ul.tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
```